# Vue 3 Composition API - TypeScript Refs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I've created a hook that will take an object of **refs** as a parameter but the function is complaining about the parameter.

Usage of my hook useValidate:

```
const test    = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const testTwo = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

const hasError = useValidate({
   'test': testRef.value,
   'testTwo': testTwo.value
})

if (!hasError) {
 // NO ERRORS
} else {
 // HAS ERROR
}
```

The hook itslef (useValidate):

```
const useValidate = (refs) => { <--- Error: Parameter 'refs' implicitly has an 'any'
    let hasErorr  = false
    const refKeys = Object.keys(refs)

    if (refKeys.length > 0) {
        refKeys.forEach(key => {
            if (refs[key] !== undefined && refs[key].v$ !== undefined) {
                refs[key].v$.$touch()

                hasErorr = refs[key].v$.$error
            }
        })
    }

    // If error, scroll to first error ref
    if (hasErorr) {
        refs[refKeys[0]].$el.scrollIntoView()
    }

    return hasErorr    
}
```

How should I define refs in the hook?
**The error says "Parameter 'refs' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)"**

Comment: How did you define the refs ?

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: TypeScript is basically asking you to define refs so it knows what to expect. Since it has no type it is defaulting to type 'any'. What you are passing in can be defined as `(refs: {[key: string]: any})` If you know that value of testTwo and testRef then change `any` to whatever that type is.

Comment: It works but I think I need to have type any because the refs include properties from the DOM and much more when I've consoled logged it and define all that is more or less impossible, right?